# Nginx conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I cannot figure out how to resolve the following warning when running `nginx -t`:

```
2022/12/29 05:10:23 [warn] 24920#24920: conflicting server name "" on 0.0.0.0:80, ignored
2022/12/29 05:10:23 [warn] 24920#24920: conflicting server name "" on [::]:80, ignored
```

I have two sites running on my server.

1. **home.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80 default_server;
    listen [::]:80 default_server;

    root /var/www/home;

    index index.html

    server_name int.mycompany.lan;

    location / {
       # First attempt to serve request as file, then
       # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

2. **bug.conf**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    listen [::]:80;

    root /var/www/bug;

    index index.html

    server_name bug.int.mycompany.lan;

    location / {
       # First attempt to serve request as file, then
       # as directory, then fall back to displaying a 404.
       try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }
 }
```

Going to the site *bug.int.mycompany.lan* always shows me the *int.mycompany.lan* site instead.

If I remove the symlink to one of these files from /etc/nginx/sites-enabled or if I change the port on one of the sites to something like 8081 then I no longer get the error above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Silly mistake. I deleted the semi-colon on the `index` line. That took me several hours to spot.

Comment: please accept your own answer to mark question as solved